# Runtime.getRuntime().exec not opening file

Tags: java, windows, runtime.exec

I wish to open this pdf file on getting the path from the database. I properly takes the filepath of the file from the database but will no open a FileProtocoleHandler. This is the code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT Pictures FROM equipments WHERE Type= ?";
        PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        update.setString(1, (String) table.getValueAt(row, 5));
        ResultSet result = update.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {

            String path = result.getString("Pictures");
            System.out.println(path);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocoleHandler" + path);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Pls post the stacktrace.

Comment: I have no clue about Windows, but I reckon you need at least a space after `FileProtocolHandler`. Also the `e` in `Protocole` in `FileProtocoleHandler` is probably not right...

Comment: Opps yes you are right. Thanks

Comment: See [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.  Also break the `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for proper delineation of arguments, particularly paths with spaces in the directories or name.